# Developing a Plugin Application

Tags: wpf, plugins, integration

Iam developing a windows application in WPF. Now I need to convert my applicaiton into a plugin for another application devloped in WPF. If I need to do that what are the procedures & concepts I have to follow ? Can any of you suggest me ?

Comment: MEF, MEF and more MEF. Did I mention MEF?

Comment: @HighCore, Is there any need that the Host application should also Implement MEF ? (or) just the plugin application only need it ?

Comment: Both host and "plugin" should implement MEF. And there should be some shared contract such as an interface or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user controls in wpf which can be used as plugin for other applications. You can give more detailed requirement for better suggestions.